# Not swapping rows of 2D matrix correctly with pointers - C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

This is a simple program. The purpose is to switch the row 'q' with the row 'q+1'. Strangely it didn't work as it should at first, not all the rows were swapped correctly. Then I brought the temp variable (`t`) outside the for and removed the `malloc` since it wasn't needed. Then it worked. Since all this seemed weird to me I reversed the code(few Ctrl+Z) and compiled again. With my surprise it still worked, the same code(with the '`t`' in the cycle and the `malloc`) that didn't work before now works. Why? I mean, is there something wrong the the code below?

```
void swap(int **a)
{
    for(int q=0;q<3;q++)
    {
        int *t=malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
        t=a[q];
        a[q]=a[q+1];
        a[q+1]=t;
        free(t);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int **a=malloc(4*sizeof(int*));
    for(int q=0;q<4;q++)
        a[q]=malloc(4*sizeof(int));

    for(int q=0;q<4;q++)
        for(int w=0;w<4;w++)
            a[q][w]=q;

    swap(a);
    for(int q=0;q<4;q++)
    {
        for(int w=0;w<4;w++)
            printf("%d ", a[q][w]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `int **` is not a 2D array and cannot point to one. You have a "jagged" array. And format the code properly.

Comment: What do you mean? That's a square matrix 4*4.

Comment: "*Why?*" perhaps you missed to re-compile the right moment. Sry, but how should we know, what you exactly *did*?

Comment: I mean, is there something wrong with the code above?

Comment: @Christian, Olaf's emphasis is on *2D*.  A C 2D array is an array of arrays.  Yours is (roughly) an array of pointers to arrays.

Comment: "*That's a square matrix 4*4.*" it can be used like one, at least in terms of indexing, but in fact it isn't. It's one+two=three pointers and one+two=three block's of memory. A real 2D-array is no pointer and one block of memory, or, if dynamically allocated, it would be one pointer and one block of memory.

Comment: The `swap` function looks dangerous. You allocate to `t` (which is not necessary at all) and the lose the handle to the memory directly in the next line by assigning `a[j]` to `t`. When you `free(t)`, you actually free a row of the original matrix. Remove the `malloc` and the `free` in `swap` and you should be fine.

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong with your code.  You assign `t=a[q]`, then free `t` and later use `a[q]`.  Being equal to `t` at the time, `a[q]` was freed, and using it later invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: A pointer to pointer is not a 2D array and can **not** be used as one. Just look up what I wrote in my first comment. Note: I did not say you use the wrong datastructure. Just the wrong name.

Comment: But dispensing with the unneeded `malloc()` and `free()` in `swap()`, the code is ok, and it produces a reasonable result.  How is the result different from what you expected?

Comment: The function `swap` does not swap q and q+1. It rolls the rows to the previous position (0<-1<-2<-3<-0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The call to `malloc()` is useless, because you immediately overwrite the returned value by assigning `a[q]` to `t`. The memory allocated is lost. This is called a memory leak.
2. The call to `free()` does not free the memory allocated by `t = malloc(...)`, but the memory allocated by `a[q] = malloc(...)`. You are destroying your array `a` row by row as `q` advances.
3. If you delete the allocation `t = malloc(...)` and the `free(t)` the code begins to approach correctness, but...
4. What it does is:

   - `a[0]` is swapped with `a[1]`, so the array `a` is now `1 0 2 3`
   - then `a[1]` is swapped with `a[2]`, so the array `a` is now `1 2 0 3`
   - then `a[2]` is swapped with `a[3]`, so the array `a` is now `1 2 3 0`